# Web Application deployment using nant scripts not happening using vs 2013 command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005, nant

I was using VS2005 previously for two web applications and was deploying the applications using vs2005 cmd prompt. But I recently migrated to VS2013 and the same nant scripts commands are not working fine when I execute them using vs2013 cmd prompt. I'm getting the below error message in at the time when it fails

External Program Failed: aspnet_compiler.exe (return code was 1)

Can somebody please help me out with this thing. One application says successfull but when I open the application using the url it says page not found.

Comment: Please provide more information such as the output of the aspnet_compiler.exe execution and the contents of nant script.

Comment: As I have mentioned already the return code is External Program Failed: aspnet_compiler.exe (return code was 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aspnet_compiler` will compile all the views (*.aspx, *.ascx, *.cshtml, etc).  It's roughly akin to running each page and validating it renders correctly.  This is a great way to validate all your pages are free from hard-to-find run-time errors.  Since aspnet_compiler ran, the issue isn't that it isn't in the path.  It may be that it's using VS 2005's aspnet_compiler or from a different framework version, but that's less likely.  More likely is that you have a syntax error in a page or user control.  Look at the build output around the "return code was 1" message and find the additional detail about the page and line that is failing.

Another not-recommended option is to comment out the aspnet_compiler line from your nant file, but you then lose all the benefits of this precompilation / validation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for Robrich for this usefull information. Is it for sure that aspnet_compiler only compiles views coz my views compilation is happening just fine for one of the applications. There are two web applications
1. Build and deployed successfully but while giving the url it says page not found.
2. Build sucessfull but while deploying when it goes to aspnet_compiler command it gives this return code 1.
So point 2 I can assume or still dig deeper to check any syntax error. But point 1 forces me to think that even if it gets deployed successfully the application is still not gonna run.

Comment: That is correct.  What ever is causing aspnet_compiler to fail will most likely fail when the page in question runs.

Comment: and how correct is this that aspnet_compiler only compiles .net framework 2.0 projects?? coz my applications are in .net 2.0 and vs 2005 is also older version. Coz if that is the case now I'm deploying using vs 2013 so maybe if it is failing there any idea??

Comment: there is a .net 4 version of aspnet_compiler in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Comment: The fact that it returns 1 is a clue.  The detail just before this in the logs will tell you much, much more than this about why.  What does the log look like?  Can you post a gist or pastebin of the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it resolved it is the problem with versioning. VS2005 dev cmd prompt by default picks aspnet_compiler from v2.0.50727 however VS2013 dev cmd prompt by default picks up from v4.0. So I replaced 
program="aspnet_compiler.exe" with program="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe" and it solved the problem for me.

Thanks all